# Oracle combining multiple and & ors

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following script :-

```
SELECT
*
FROM
    view_pending_comm
WHERE
    (ok_to_gen = 'Y' AND comm_type = 'Maya' AND stage <> 3 OR stage <> 6 OR stage <> 9)
OR
    (ok_to_gen = 'Y' AND comm_type = 'Sapphire' AND stage <> 2)
```

What I need to do is return records where the comm_type is Maya, but not stage 3, 6, or 9
and also where the comm_type is Sapphire, but not stage 2. ok_to_gen needs to be Y in all cases.

I tried the script above, but this also returns records where comm_type is Sapphire and stage is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  view_pending_comm
WHERE (ok_to_gen = 'Y' AND comm_type = 'Maya' AND stage NOT IN (3, 6, 9)) OR
    (ok_to_gen = 'Y' AND comm_type = 'Sapphire' AND stage <> 2)
```

The issue is the logic issue of connecting inequalities.  The correct logic is:

```
stage = 3 or stage = 6 or stage = 9
```

However, the negation uses `and`:

```
stage <> 3 and stage <> 6 and stage <> 9
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation.